# Cloning a private github repo without credentials?

Tags: git, authentication, github, credentials, git-gui

I'm new to git and github, so forgive me if this somehow sounds stupid.

After much needless frustration with trying to find a git gui client, I had a major facepalm when I realized that git came with a GUI. Thusly, I ended my search and proceeded to redownload a test repository I made on github.

HOWEVER, after putting in the ***private repo address*** and a target folder, I somehow downloaded the repo without a credential prompt of any kind for github. I did make a commit earlier when I was testing things on another client that was buggier than I liked.

Is this normal behavior or a serious bug? Why is github not checking for anything? Did git store my github account details? How do I stop this functionality?

I am terrified...help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git generally uses a public/private key mechanism for transfers, not a password login. Your GUI may have automatically configured this for you, but if your repo is private it will not be accessible without authentication.

Comment: I just realized that I somehow created a personal access token and forgot about it. Thank you though. Your answer definitely helped a lot and saved me from a mental freak out.

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me but the problem was that my credentials were stored in **Windows Credentials** *(Credential Manager from control panel if you are using windows)*. This usually happens when you have logged in to your GitHub account in the browser and **Git Bash v2.36.1** which I am using asks for a one-time password unlike the `git config --global credential.helper` which only stores the credentials for *15 mins*.